# HttpURLConnection connect() Exception on 4.0 & 4.1 but not on 2.3.3

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android app doesn’t work on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429430/android-app-doesnt-work-on-android-4)

I'm working on an android app. trying to find the solution for hours. My app works fine with the database and server when I'm running emulator 2.3.3 but no on 4.0 or 4.1 or any version above 2.3.3. the app throws an exception in this method: the exception happens when trying to do `connection.connect();` please help.

```
public void sendOutputLine(URL url, String outputLine) {
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "1");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "2");    
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "3");    
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "4");    
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(outputLine.length());
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "5");    
        connection.connect();
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "6");    
        out = connection.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        pw.print(outputLine);
        pw.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG,
                "SocketTimeoutException sendOutputLine(): " + e.getMessage());          
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG,
                "Protocol exception sendOutputLine(): " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "IO exception sendOutputLine(): "
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG,
                "Exception bommed client: " + e.getMessage());  
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): outputLint: Login%a@a%57963634
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): 1
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): 2
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): 3
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): 4
11-17 13:19:11.710: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): 5
11-17 13:19:11.740: D/SocialFamilyTree(847): Exception bommed client: null
```

**EDIT**:
I see, so I need to use `AsyncTask`

How do I use the `AsyncTask` for this task?

Answer (score 0):

use AsyncTask by this way...

```
public class getConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
    {


           @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
           {
               super.onPreExecute();
               Utils.clearDialogs();
               Utils.showActivityViewer(Mainctivity.this);
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0)
           {

            try 
            {
                   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "1");
                   connection.setDoInput(true);
                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "2");    
                   connection.setDoOutput(true);
                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "3");    
                   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "4");    
                   connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(outputLine.length());
                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "5");    
                   connection.connect();
                   Log.d(LogInActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "6");    
                   out = connection.getOutputStream();
                   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
                   pw.print(outputLine);
                   pw.flush();
                   out.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
           {
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               Utils.hideActivityViewer();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
             Log.v("log", e.toString());
            }
           }

          }
```

Comment: this is the class..where i declared the show and hide function of my progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

Don't just blindly catch Exception.  You're masking the entire problem by hiding the error.  If I had to guess, I'd say you're encountering NetworkOnMainThreadException, because you're probably not running on a background thread, but it's impossible to tell with the information you've provided.

AsyncTask is one approach to solving the NetworkOnMainThreadException problem, but it's not the only approach, and there's no evidence that's your actual problem.