# HttpURLConnection POST-request throws IOException

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to make a **POST-request** using android **HttpUrlConnection**. First I use the example for GET-request from here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client

It works perfectly (for example I get *google.com* page). Then I make some changes to make a POST-request: change the request method on POST:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

and add this code (got from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
      OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());     
      out.close();
```

So now the method downloadUrl looks like this:

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
  InputStream is = null;
  // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
  // web page content.
  int len = 500;

  try {
      URL url = new URL(myurl);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
      conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

      conn.setDoInput(true);

      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
      OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());     
      out.close();

      // Starts the query
      conn.connect();
      int response = conn.getResponseCode();
      Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
      is = conn.getInputStream();

      // Convert the InputStream into a string
      String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
      return contentAsString;

  // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
  // finished using it.
  } finally {
      if (is != null) {
          is.close();
      } 
  }
}
```

And it always throws **IOException**. Could you help me, what is wrong?

Comment: Er... on which line does it throw the `IOException`?!

Comment: On  `is = conn.getInputStream();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sold this problem: the thing was the server didn't accept POST-requests on the selected URL. Changing URL (and server) led to successful request without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Android won't let you start a network connection on the main UI thread. You have to start a background thread (use `AsyncTask`) and do it from there.

More detail [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429430/android-app-doesnt-work-on-android-4).

Comment: I use AsyncTask exactly the way it is illustrated in the http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client. When I don't use AsyncTask GET-request also throws exception (but not IOException). But in my case GET-request works. I'm totaly confused and got no idea what to do with this...